# Gráfico dinámico 2D en Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hola a todos soy nuevo en python y quisiera si alguien podría ayudarme , quiero graficar 2 variables que generan números random en python :

```
import random
import time

while True:
    # Generar números aleatorios entre 1 y 10 para dos variables
    numero1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    numero2 = random.randint(1, 10)

    # Imprimir los números generados
    print("Número 1:", numero1)
    print("Número 2:", numero2)

    # Esperar un tiempo antes de generar nuevos números
    time.sleep(1)  # Espera 1 segundo
```

He visto una librería llamada matplotlib pero no se como hacer para que se pueda obtener un grafico en 2 D y que se este siempre actualizando con el cambio de las variables y se vea algo así , donde el eje x sea la variable 1 y el y la variable 2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]